# Joomla : whenever i change URL rewriting and enable htaccess get error

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

My site was working fine for the last couple of months and suddenly stopped working. and the issue was backend was working fine but the front end does not load at all.

then I contacted server providers they saying they have not done any changes to the server and asking me to contact Joomla support to see any in-depth errors. they even said they cant find any issues from the logs.

Then what I did was I reinstall VirtueMart (mind you this is an e-commerce site). then it started to work again from the front end. but I realize follow on pages aren't working. so what I did was I remove url re-writing and change the .htaccess code to txt.

so the issue I am having now is I can see index.php file in the URL. but whenever I try to change use url rewriting and enable .htaccess I get this error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@domain.au and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly stopped working, without any change from your end ?
Try to step backward and recall anything you did before the issues.

The virtuemart re-installation should not have any relation with the SEF settings and the htaccess. 
All these seem to be a combination of different issues.
Have you made any changes on the htaccess file ?

Go in Joomla Global configuration and disable SEF settings. Set URL rewriting to No. Then try to load pages in the front-end.

If you need SEF URLs, follow these instructions about how to enable this feature in Joomla:
http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

Comment: Hi, No i have not done any modifications. Site was working fine. but the issue i am having is I cant get rid of index.php. I have reinstalled virtuemart and installed most of my extensions and templates. But still i get that error. I cant get .htaccess enable.

Comment: index.php is related to the url rewriting and is not something that can be changed by re-installing extensions. Try what I have suggested you above. First, disable all SEF settings in global configuration, to  see if your pages are loading as expected, then follow the instructions from Joomla.

Comment: did you check if you were hacked? the fact that reinstalling VM worked (at least non-sef) hints to it. But if you want to get quickly back on track, have a backup restored, and analyze the site against malicious code and vulnerabilities

Comment: Hi Guys, is there anyway i can check whether its being hacked or not. but anyway i dont know how to get rid of index.php in the url